# Sending SQL emails using AWS and SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I hope someone will be able to help me with this since I am new with AWS stuff.

I have a Web App using .NET MVC which will be deployed/hosted in AWS. This is the description of what I would like to achieve:

1- Let's say that the Web App will insert products in a Products Table on SQL Server.

2- When this product is inserted, the system (AWS) will send an email to a Client from a Clients Table on SQL Server.

- Is that possible with AWS?
- Could I set a trigger in SQL Server and send an email by SES?
- Is it better to use SQS?. So the Web App will publish messages in SQS, and then having another app listening and sending those emails, for instance a console app.

I will appreciate any direction or useful link.

Thanks all of you in advance.

Comment: Why you do not put the SNS request directly to the function where you add product? I could not see any benefit of using triggers, SQS etc etc. I think you would be complicating unnecessarily with all of these. (If the performance is your concern, a SNS request takes the same time as a SQS request.)

Comment: Well...it is not about performance. It is about separation of responsibilities. Anyway, let's say that having the notification service externally to the app is a fix requirement. What would be the best way to do it with AWS? . Thanks for answering

Comment: You can use SQS and consume the queue from an console application. As MatteoSP says in his answer then triggering from the database would infringe the principle of seperation of responsibilities. Just fire an event to SQS and process the message in another application, you can send message, send mobile notification, whatever you want from this seperate application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is 'yes'. Yes SQL server can use SES to send emails. Because SQL server can send emails, all you need to do is set it up to use the correct SMTP settings from SES once your account is verified and working with SES.

That said, I would never have my db server send emails, just doesn't seem like the right place to do it; even though you can.

I have developed and support several systems like this, and the usual pattern I use is to have the web application insert a message in an SQS queue that will be used as input to another process to send the email out. When possible I like to include all the details about the email into the SQS message, i.e. from, to, subject and the body - everything the downstream process will need to know to send them out.

In my case I use a windows service running on several EC2 instances in an autoscale group to poll the queue and send the emails out. In most cases, where I was able to store all the emails in the SQS body, the windows service is completely general purpose - it reads an SQS message, composes the email and sends it out. Because all of the details of the email are within the SQS message body, this single SQS queue and the windows service that is processing it, can process emails from a variety of applications because the service doesn't need to contain any business logic specific to the application and has no external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As you talk about separation of responsibilities, I can't see anything less indicated to send email than a db server (even if it can do it).Sending emails is a task for your business layer, surely not for the data layer.

Use the web app to trigger the process of sending the emails, than implement it directly into the web app, or separate it with a messaging system (like SNS), with a queue system (like SQS) or whatever else.

Comment: You are totally right about DB, it should not have this responsibility. My comment about that was because I did not know if the other way is possible with AWS. I have just started to read about it. I still think that the web app should not have this responsibility either. It is better, as you said, separate it with a messaging system. Any useful link about it?. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean about SNS? I could not recommend anything better than the reference documentation, see: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sns/. SNS is really simple to use.